# Electronic circuit troubleshooting resin - is it normal?

Tags: troubleshooting, circuits

I have just started my first electronics troubleshooting project of trying to fix our family's toaster. One of the first things I learned was that capacitors tend to be commonly faulty parts of a circuit and so by visually inspecting the board you can assess a little bit of whether or not one of them is causing the issue.

Pictures of the board:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

From what I saw the capacitors looked fine, no swelling or weird ooze coming out of them but there are a few resin-like blobs close to some of the capacitors and I'm unsure why they are there.

- Were they meant to keep the capacitors stuck in a certain position?
- Is there even a purpose for them?
- Are they a sign of deterioration, like an overheated board for example?

Comment: That's there intentionally, there's nothing wrong with the capacitor.

Comment: The blobs you see are glue to hold the capacitors in place. Electrolytic capacitors can be bad and not show any external signs like swelling and oozing goo. You need to remove them and test, preferably on an impedance analyzer. You can use a capacitance meter, but that will only test if the capacitance is OK, not ESR which is important on switching power supplies.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answers, that is all I needed! I will remove the capacitors and test them individually and check their capacitance. Now that I know that the blobs are just glue then it is more straightforward

Comment: I am curious, what toaster has a defrost button? It has an interesting feature if the toast does not get hot enough you cancel the defrost cycle:-)

Comment: `Is there even a purpose for them?` manufacturers do not waste resources by adding useless parts to a product ... unless the whole product is bogus to start with

Comment: ***DANGER !!!!*** ... touching any part of that board, when the toaster is plugged in, can have fatal consequences

Comment: @Gil I guess it must be some lower heating mode? I've never seen it before, my parents just asked me to fix it and so I only noticed it recently. I'll be careful and make sure I have electrically resistant gloves

Comment: @Gil "defrost" is sometimes just a short fixed time to thaw bread badly, or, more likely labelled "frozen", an extra time to go from frozen to toasted without fiddling.  Not very useful either way.

Comment: @Baguji you are liekly, at first, not to need to do any live working - keep it that way as long as possible, and do some more research before powering it up bare

Comment: Thanks yeah I'll keep that in mind, I want to avoid powering it on as much as possible

Comment: You should probably check the heating elements, fuse, and thermal fuse first.

Comment: re: "capacitors tend to be commonly faulty parts of a circuit" is not completely accurate - electrolytic caps tend to be, and this most often manifests in the power supply section of the circuit, where a failed/failing cap will have very visible effects on the rest of the system. That looks like a control board for your toaster, it is very unlikely that the issue is there. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I have never seen it before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The capacitors are glued to the circuit board to keep them steadily in place so their conductors don't get worn out due to mechanical stresses, like shocks and vibration.

That's normal.

The capacitors also look just fine, so you can't visually check if they are OK or faulty.

Comment: Thank you, that's all the confirmation I needed. Just wanted to know if this was actual glue or if it's some side effect of leakage or overheating somewhere!

Comment: +1: A toaster is definately going to see frequent mechanical shocks.

Comment: It's often hot glue, though perhaps not in a toaster that gets warm anyway.  If you need to get it off, a craft knife heated with a lighter or hot air gun will make short work of hot glue, but not alternatives

Comment: So actually OP has broken the strain relief by pulling tha capacitor up, away from the hot glue. He should remove the now-useless cold hot glue and re-glue.

Answer (score 2):

I will start this repair job focusing on what the machine should do and what is not doing...

check obvious things first like: "is the board powered as it should be ? "

board is very simple the fault will be simple too.

Comment: I stripped our toaster down, when one side stopped staying down. The cages are held down with an electromagnet. After getting it a part, and losing several knuckles on the razor-sharp edges, I found a crumb stopping the plate touching the coil.